# Is there way to give error in grunt build when source files are not using linux line endings?

Tags: development-environment, gruntjs

When building a project,
could be useful to force linux line endings to detect
 early problems in multi platform teams.

Forcing linux line endings
in development all through out the a project sounds to me like
a nice step forward like when I switched to utf-8 :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using git, you could let git [solve it](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings).

Otherwise, [grunt-beautify](https://github.com/pix/grunt-beautify) has an option [endOfLineCharacters](https://github.com/divdavem/grunt-beautify/commit/d13f626cc96cf00fc14b0da00cc9440f800aa5c2). But that module seems dead.

Answer (score 0):

"grunt" pays attention to platform specific line feed.

You can force grunt to use on every platform the same line feed char. Do this at top of your grunt file:

```
// overwrite platform specific setting get always unix like line end
grunt.util.linefeed = '\n';
```

That option is documented here:

http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.util#grunt.util.linefeed

Answer (score 0):

Use [.editorconfig](http://editorconfig.org/) files

These make it really easy to set cross-platform line endings in a consistent manner across the team without the need for an additional build step. They are enforced any time you save a file.

Here's [an example file which also uses spaces as tabs](https://github.com/bevacqua/unbox/blob/master/.editorconfig)

```
# editorconfig.org
root = true

[*]
indent_style = space
indent_size = 4
end_of_line = lf
charset = utf-8
trim_trailing_whitespace = true
insert_final_newline = true

[*.md]
trim_trailing_whitespace = false
```